# Create user but checking if exist in Active Directory with PHP

Tags: php, symfony, active-directory, doctrine, ldap

I'm working with Symfony 2.8.2, Doctrine.

I need to create users in my app data base, but first I need to check if those users exist on a external Active Directory database. Only if the user exist it will possible to create the user on the app data base. My code works for creat users, but now I'm trying to implementate the "check if the user exist first"  section, I'm following some examples but I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it goes well. I've read that the usual sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search result, close connection. Could someone give me a hint on what should I do with my code, where should I do the search first, before or after the bind? and why.

```
public function createAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post_send = $request->request->get('userbundle_user');

    if (array_key_exists('id', $post_send)) {
        $ldap_success = true;
        $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($post_send['id']);
    }else{
        $ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.0.0.230");
        $Pass= "XXXXXX";
        $searchUser = "YYYYYY";
        $ldap_success = false;
        if (@ldap_bind($ldapconn, $searchUser, $Pass)) {
            try{
                $post_send['password'] = $Pass;
                $attributes = ['cn'];
                $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userPrincipalName=".ldap_escape($post_send['username'], null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER)."))";
                $baseDn = "DC=XXX,DC=XX,DC=cl";
                $results = @ldap_search($ldapconn, $baseDn, $filter);
                //$info = @ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $results);
                if ( $results ) {
                    $ldap_success = true;
                } else {
                    $ldap_success = false;//false, lo deje en true para que pudiera avanzar
                }
            }
            catch(\Exception $e){
                $ldap_success = false;
            }
        }
        $entity = new User();
    }

    if( $ldap_success ){
        $entity->setUsername($post_send['username']);
        $entity->setRut($post_send['rut']);
        //$entity->setSalt("ssss");
        if (array_key_exists('password', $post_send)) {
            if ( $post_send['password'] != "" ) {
                $entity->setPassword($post_send['password']);
                $this->setSecurePassword($entity);
            }
        }
        $entity->setEmail($post_send['email']);
        $entity->setDateAdded(new \DateTime());
        $entity->setIsActive(true);
        $entity->setIsAdmin(true);
        $entity->setUserRoles($em->getRepository('UserBundle:Role')->find( $post_send['admin_roles_id'] ));
        $entity->setWizardCompleted(true);
        $entity->setPath("s");
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $json = new JsonUtils();
        return $json->arrayToJson(array("id"=>$entity->getId()));
    }
    return $json->arrayToJson( array("sueccess"=>false ) );
}
```

There's a question here [How do I make a ldap search with anonymous binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695739/how-do-i-make-a-ldap-search-with-anonymous-binding) related yo my problem, with no answers at all.

Comment: Are the `$post_send['username']` and `$post_send['password']` credentials for the user that is logging into the site? If that case all you really need to do is verify if a `ldap_bind()` works. You could also use the builtin [LDAP component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html) or a bundle like [LdapTools](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle).

Comment: No, are new parameters, they are from a "Create new User" form. But the binding is working ok. Till now I wasn't verificating if the user that I want to create exist in AD, but I was using the bind while login to the system.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I didn't realize this was in the controller. Whoops. I think what you really need is a LDAP service account that is only a member of the "Domain Users" group (thus having read-only access). Then you could use that account's username/password to bind and query to see if the username they're attempting to create in the form actually exists in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your AD query to check if the user exists (starting at the beginning of your else statement), I would make the logic something like this:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.0.0.230");
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
// Use a LDAP service account with only read access...
$searchUser = 'user@myDomain.com';
$searchPass = '12345';

$ldap_success = false;
if (@ldap_bind($ldapconn, $searchUser, $searchPass)) {
    $attributes = ['cn'];
    $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userPrincipalName=".ldap_escape($post_send['username'], null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER)."))";
    $baseDn = "DC=myDomain,DC=com";
    $results = @ldap_search($ldapconn, $baseDn, $filter, $attributes);
    $info = @ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $results);

    $ldap_success = ($info && $info['count'] === 1);
}
```

In that case `$ldap_success` would only be `true` if a user exists in AD with the [UPN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx) specified.

However, if you are requiring the user's password and binding to AD, then there is no reason to also verify that the user can be found via a query after binding. In that case simply binding to AD is evidence enough that they exist in AD.

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking this. No, I'm not requiring the user's password anymore. I only have to check with the username passed by post. I'm going to modify the form because password isn't required anymore. I think you answer will works.

Comment: I can't find user with that code. It always returns me false the $results. The bind is ok. I'm using of course my $baseDn = "DC=XXXXX,DC=XX,DC=cl";

Comment: Add a `var_dump($post_send['username'])`, what does that show? The username would have to be in "email" format (ie. `username@domain.com`).

Comment: I'm using samaccountname so people don't need to put the entire name@domain. Thanks, your code is the main structure now of my solution. It's all working. I'll pick as a correct answer.